# How to insert json data in React js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a following list of data's. I need to insert my template. How to achieve this one with React js.

```
[
 {
  product:"one",
  quantiy:2
 },
 {
  product:"two",
  quantiy:4
 },
 {
  product:"three",
  quantiy:3
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working jsbin example http://jsbin.com/ziqelujevi/2/edit?html,js,output

Update: Display all the items http://jsbin.com/cibuhogudu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: How to display all data's?

Comment: Thank u so mach @andrei. This is what i want. If it is multi dimensional array means, how the code structure will be?

Comment: @Sathya depends on what that data means. But essentially it will be the same only that the map function will get more complicated (now an element in the .map function means a row so more processing will be in place). Continuing on this idea maybe you want to have something where in the map function you do `return <ChildComponent data={el}/>` so you pass along the rendering to a child.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code: http://jsbin.com/wafemul/edit?html,js,output

```
var data = [
 {
   product:"one",
   quantiy:2
 },
 {
   product:"two",
   quantiy:4
  },
 {
  product:"three",
  quantiy:3
 }
];

class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
  super(props);
   this.state= {
    data: data
   }
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <div>{this.state.data.map( item => (
       <li>{item.product}</li>
       ))}
      </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('box')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a propety to the component and you can access it using this.props.data in the render method.

Ex:

```js
var data  =  [....]
<SampleComponent data={data} />,
```

Or use state to pass data

Comment: Hi @Bijeshp009. Can u give me the fiddle example?

Comment: have a look at this it is a straight forward approach : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html